# write function doubles \n

Tags: python-3.x, file-handling

I´m writing right now on a program, that extracts parts of other files and places them into different files. For this I am using the encoding ISO-8859-1. But everytime I want to write the new file, the single bytes change and every \n gets doubled.

The "magic" only happens in the line `output.write(message)`

Here is my code, that writes the code into the file:

```
with open(output_path, "w+", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as output:
    for m in message:
        print(repr(m))
    output.write(message)
```

I use the loop to see the single bytes

This is the result it gives me:

```
'\x00'
'\n'
'\x00'
'\n'
'\x00'
'\x1d'
```

and this is what I see in the file:

```
'\x00'
'\n'
'\n'
'\x00'
'\n'
'\n'
'\x00'
'\x1d'
```

You can see \n got doubled.

Comment: And your question is how to replace double `\n` with only one?

Comment: Is it possible your `message` contains lines like `\\n\n`?

Comment: I always assume there is stuff in the files that is throwing off my formatting.  When I grab a line from the file I will use rstrip .... line = m.rstrip() will remove any of the pesky stuff and then when I re-write the file, just throw in the "\n" where I actually want them.

Comment: @gbeaven My questions are _why is this happening?_ and _how can I fix it?

Comment: @blueteeth the upper result shows that the string `message` contains only one `\n` and then a `\x00` and after this the next `\n` so there is not this situation: `\\n\n`